# OO way or functional way of string comparison conditionals in php

Tags: php, oop, functional-programming

I am `curl`ing on a specific page that returns only `html`. To determine what page it returns, I simply try to `stripos` the result of the `curl`

Like so:

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if(stripos($result, 'success') !== false) {
    // do something
} else {
  if (stripos($result, 'foo') !== false) {
      // do something
  } else if (stripos($result, 'foo') !== false) {
      // do something
  } else if (stripos($result, 'bar') !== false) {
      // do something
  } else if (stripos($result, 'bazz') !== false) {
      // do something
  } else {
      // do something
  }
}
```

This is quite messy I think, is there an OO way or functional way to solve this kind of problem if I were looking at minimal `if` statements or ultimately an `if-less` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are searching for a ways of abstraction. In this example you are repeating yourself in  case analysis and this might be the best approach if the "do something" is very different and not consistent.

```php
$map = [ 'success' => function () { return 1; }, 
         'foo'     => function () { return 2; }, 
         'bar'     => function () { return 3; }, 
         'bazz'    => function () { return 4; } ];
foreach ( $map as $search => $value )
{
  if (stripos($result, $search) !== false )
  {
    return call_user_func($value);
  }
}
```

In my example these could just have been constants and we could just return them instead of applying a function. In a functional pattern this would be like the function `any` in Scheme SRFI-1 except it returns it's true value:

```php
// This function uses PHP 5.6 ellipsis
function array_any(callable $callable, ...$arrays) {
  if( count($arrays) == 1 ) {
      $args_zipped = array_map( function ($x) { return [$x]; }, $arrays[0]);
  } else {
      array_unshift( $arrays, null);
      $args_zipped = call_user_func_array( "array_map", $arrays);
  }
  foreach ( $args_zipped as $args ) {
    $result = call_user_func_array($callable, $args);
    if( $result !== false )
      return $result;
  }
  return false;
}

array_any( function ($search, $value) { 
               if ( stripos($result, $search) !== false )
                   return $value;
                   return false;
           },
           array_keys($map),
           array_values($map));
```

The function in itself uses linear update, but as you can see it works similar to `array_map`.

Answer (score 0):

This simple function would do that work:

```
function checkWord ($haystack,$needle){
foreach ($needle as $word) {
    if (stripos($haystack, $word) !== false) {
        echo $word." was found!<br/>";
    }
    else{
        echo $word." wasn't found<br/>";
    }
  }
}

checkWord("Hello what's up?",array('Hello','Huhud','up','?'));
```

This will output:-

```
Hello was found!
Huhud wasn't found
up was found!
? was found!
```